# Pythonic way to select first variable that evaluates to True

Tags: python

I have some variables and I want to select the first one that evaluates to True, or else return a default value.

For instance I have `a`, `b`, and `c`. My existing code:

```
result = a if a else (b if b else (c if c else default))
```

Another approach I was considering:

```
result = ([v for v in (a, b, c) if v] + [default])[0]
```

But they both feel messy, so is there a more Pythonic way?

Comment: i don't know about "pythonic" but i like the first one. nice and lispy and easy to read :)

Comment: How do you mean "defined"? If b is undefined, for example, then you'll get a NameError. Your code checks if the variables are defined but empty/zero/False.

Comment: Note that in Python you don't define variables, you bind names to objects.

Comment: -1: The question doesn't make sense compared with the example code.  Please fix the question to say "non-None" and provide some better explanation for why this even matters.  Setting a variable is -- perhaps -- the most profound operation -- it advances the state of the computation.  The idea that it's "ambiguous" and not deeply intentional subverts the very idea of a program that does something purposeful.

Comment: Are you sure you really do mean "having a True value"? It's pretty common to write this code when your "undefined" actually means "is None". For example: you can have a few things that are either a string or `None`, and the empty string may be a valid value...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you mean returning first value for what `bool(value)==True`? Then you can just rely on the fact that [boolean operators return last evaluated argument](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

```
result = a or b or c or default
```

Comment: N.B (to the OP) the empty string (`""`) has a false boolean value (`bool("") == False`); keep that in mind if you don't consider it "false" in your program. Same applies to `()` (empty tuple), `{}` (empty dict), `[]` (empty list) and zero (in any numeric type).

Answer (score 17):

If one variable is not "defined", you can't access its name. So any reference to 'a' raises a NameError Exception.

In the other hand, if you have something like:

```
a = None
b = None
c = 3
```

you can do

```
default = 1
r = a or b or c or default
# r value is 3
```

Comment: Wouldn't either of the two options the asker presented run into the same NameErrorException?

Comment: That's right. You can't read a variable before assigning something to it.

Answer (score 5):

So long as `default` evaluates to True:

```
result = next((x for x in (a, b, c, d , e, default) if x))
```

Comment: If you've decided to use `next`, you might as well use its `default` argument

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this (in contrast to the other answers this is a solution where you don't **have** to define the 'missing' values as being either `None` or `False`):

```
b = 6
c = 8

def first_defined(items):
    for x in items:
        try:
            return globals()[x]
            break
        except KeyError:
            continue

print first_defined(["a", "b", "c"])
```

In order to avoid NameErrors when a, b or c isn't defined: give the function a list of strings instead of variable references (you can't pass non-existing references). If you are using variables outside the 'globals()' scope, you could use getattr with its default argument.

--

If a, b and c are defined, I'd go for something like this (considering the fact that an empty string, None or False evaluate to a boolean `False`):

```
a = None
b = 6
c = 8

def firstitem(items):
    for x in items:
        if x:
            return x
            break
        else:
            continue

print firstitem([a, b, c])
```

Comment: You don't need to `break` after a return: you're already out of the loop. You also don't need to `else: continue` at the end of a loop: that's what would happen anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this works in every case, but this works for this case.

```
a = False
b = "b"
c = False
default = "default"
print a or b or c or default # b
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
a=None  
b=None  
c=None  
val= reduce(lambda x,y:x or y,(a,b,c,"default"))  
print val
```

The above prints `"default"`. If any of the inputs is defined, `val` would contain the first defined input.

Answer (score 1):

If by `defined` you mean `ever assigned any value whatsoever to in any scope accessible from here`, then trying to access an "undefined" variable will raise a NameError exception (or some subclass thereof, but catching NameError will catch the subclass too).  So, the simplest way to perform, literally, the absolutely weird task you ask about, is:

```
for varname in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
  try: return eval(varname)
  except NameError: pass
return default
```

Any alleged solution lacking a try/except won't work under the above meaning for "defined". Approaches based on exploring specific scopes will either miss other scopes, or be quite complex by trying to replicate the scope-ordering logic that `eval` does for you so simply.

If by "defined" you actually mean "assigned a value that evaluates to true (as opposed to false)", i.e., all values are actually **defined** (but might happen to be false, and you want the first true value instead), then the already-proposed `a or b or c or default` becomes the simplest approach. But that's a totally different (and even weirder!) meaning for the word "defined"!-)